# Clicking a checkbox on Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

For some reason I cannot find a way to click a box on this website: https://www.rlcarriers.com/freight/shipping/rate-quote

```
<div id="residential-delivery" class="input-checkbox accessorial" style="">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Residential/Limited Access Delivery field is required." id="Accessorials_ResidentialDelivery" name="Accessorials.ResidentialDelivery" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Accessorials.ResidentialDelivery" type="hidden" value="false">
<div class="input-label-tip">
<label for="Accessorials_ResidentialDelivery">Residential/Limited Access Delivery</label>



bot.FindElement (By.XPath("//input[@name='Accessorials.ResidentialDelivery' and @id='Accessorials_ResidentialDelivery']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use FindElement object by XPath.

```
Dim checkboxElement As WebElement
Set checkboxElement = YourWebDriverObj.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@name='Accessorials.ResidentialDelivery' and @id='Accessorials_ResidentialDelivery']"))

checkboxElement.Click
```